# How to increase performance of WSO2 Idenity server

Tags: wso2, identityserver4, identity, wso2-identity-server

I have set up wso2 Identity server 5.3.0 with my web applications. Its working smooth for less number of policies and roles. As soon as number of policy and roles are getting increased the getDecision method from EntitlementService web service. Even worst thing is sometimes its giving time out.

Ant lead, How to improve getDecision method performance or caching ?

Let me know if you need other information below in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

@Mak you can use XACML policy caching technique to improve the performance. Please refer  below document to improve the performance.
https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS550/Improving+XACML+PDP+Performance+with+Caching+Techniques